# Angular: Filter data from service in a component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class `DataService` which fetches data from the backend:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getEntries() : Observable<Array<DataEntry>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<DataEntry>>('http://192.168.0.103:3000/data');
  }

  getSensors() : Observable<Array<Sensor>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<Sensor>>('http://192.168.0.103:3000/sensor');
  }
}
```

and a `FilterCollectionComponent` which contains various `FilterComponent`s (at the moment it is only one but in the future there will be many):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter-collection',
  templateUrl: './filter-collection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter-collection.component.css']
})
export class FilterCollectionComponent implements OnInit {

  _FilterType = FilterType;
  completeData : DataEntry[] = [];

  @ViewChild('dateRangeFilter') dateRangeFilter?: ElementRef<FilterComponent>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  onFilterApply() : void {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getEntries().subscribe(data => {
      this.completeData = data;
    });
  }

}
```

With this HTML:

```
<mat-label>Datefilter:</mat-label>
<div style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 1rem;"></div>
<app-filter #dateRangeFilter [filter]="_FilterType.DateRangeFilter"></app-filter>
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="onFilterApply()">
    Apply
    <mat-icon>filter_alt</mat-icon>
</button>
```

I have two angular components which need the data from the data service to display them.
Now, I don't want them to directly subscribe to the raw data, instead I want them to subscribe to an event from the `FilterCollectionComponent` after the raw data has been filtered (the user can filter the data at any moment).

I am not very familiar with Angular - any idea what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you may be able to use a BehaviorSubject and subscribe to that instead. Start it with a null value and do a check if it is null on initial subscription. If it is, don't apply a filter... Here's a small example:
https://dev.to/sabrinasuarezarrieta/little-example-on-how-to-use-behaviorsubject-observable-in-angular-6ec

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. FilterCollectionComponent : change completeData to Observable Type:

```
completeData$ : Observable<DataEntry[]> = of([]);
```

Step 2. FilterCollectionComponent : Change in onInit

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.completeData$ = this.dataService.getEntries();
}
```

Step 3. FilterCollectionComponent Template : Your Child components will access data from FilterCollectionComponent's  completeData$ Observable, where subscription/unsubscription will be taken care by [AsyncPype](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

```
<app-filter [dataEntries]="completeData$ | async" #dateRangeFilter1 [filter]="_FilterType.DateRangeFilter"></app-filter>

<app-filter [dataEntries]="completeData$ | async" #dateRangeFilter2 [filter]="_FilterType.YYFilter"></app-filter>

<app-filter [dataEntries]="completeData$ | async" #dateRangeFilter3 [filter]="_FilterType.XXFilter"></app-filter>
```

To access `dataEntries` in `<app-filter>`. For performance you can use   `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,` in your `AppFilterComponent` if he is really a
[Presentational Component](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/presentational-components-with-angular-3961)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    App Filter Works!!
    <ul *ngFor="let item of dataEntries">
      <li>{{ item.id }} | {{ item.name }} | {{ item.city }}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class AppFilterComponent {
  name = 'Filter';

  @Input()
  dataEntries: DataEntry[];
}
```

In your filter method just assign filtered data to `this.completeData$` and will affect in all children `<app-filter>`

```
onFilterApply() : void {

  this.completeData$ = //api call
  //Or Example filter by john name
   this.completeData$ = this.completeData$.pipe(
    switchMap(dataEntryList =>
      of(dataEntryList.filter(item => item.name === 'John'))
    )
  );
}
```

Furthermore, you can also filter data for each `<app-filter>` need so that you do not need to provide `[filter]="_FilterType.XXFilter"` to each child. But now hopefully I think it's enough as per your question.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzlnqz)